# No user data on crash reports

Tags: ios, crashlytics, google-fabric

I'm setting user data to Crashlytics when user logs in

```
Crashlytics.sharedInstance().setUserIdentifier(user.id)
Crashlytics.sharedInstance().setUserName(user.fullName)
Crashlytics.sharedInstance().setUserEmail(user.email)
```

I see this info on my other apps (android and objective C) but not on this one, implemented in Swift.

Any ideas why?

```
pod 'Fabric', '= 1.7.7'
pod 'Crashlytics', '= 3.10.2'
```

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. Are you setting this on each launch of the app?

Comment: Hi Mike, no, I'm setting it once when the user logs in

Comment: Gotcha, if the crash happens before that point, then we don't have the information to display in the crash.

Comment: Crashes are happening after this data is set, but for some reason this data is not being displayed with the crashes.